# SQL Server deadlock on junction table

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I'm confronted with a deadlock on a junction table while one process deletes some entry and another process select another entry (in SQL Server 2014).

Schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Junction
(
    JunctionId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Table1Id INT NOT NULL,
    Table2Id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Table1Id) REFERENCES Table1(Table1Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (Table2Id) REFERENCES Table2(Table2Id) 
)

CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    Table1Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    SomeData1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
    Table2Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    SomeData2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Deadlock graph looks like this:

[image: deadlock graph]

Deadlock graph xml :

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process18679f088">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process18679f088" taskpriority="0" logused="0"             
        waitresource="PAGE: 6:1:19957 " waittime="4855" ownerId="5887063"
        transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2019-01-19T18:12:40.450" 
        XDES="0x1ba3aba20" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="11756" 
        status="suspended" spid="63" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0"     
        trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2019-01-19T18:12:40.450" 
        lastbatchcompleted="2019-01-19T18:12:40.453" lastattention="1900-01-
        01T00:00:00.453" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"     
        hostname="WIN-*****" hostpid="96380" loginname="WIN-
        J***" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" 
        xactid="5887063" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295"         
        clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="GetSmth" 
            line="5" stmtstart="132" stmtend="1010" 
            sqlhandle="0x03000600ea777e2c037f2301bea9000001.....">
       SELECT t2.Table2Id, SomeData2 FROM Table2 t2 
       INNER JOIN Junction j ON t2.Table2Id=j.Table2Id
       WHERE Table1Id=@table1Id     
      </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf> Proc [Database Id = 6 Object Id = 746485738]</inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process1867be108" taskpriority="0" logused="363700" 
            waitresource="PAGE: 6:1:19956 " waittime="4021" 
            ownerId="5887012" transactionname="user_transaction" 
            lasttranstarted="2019-01-19T18:12:40.030" XDES="0x1c7aae700" 
            lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="85928" status="suspended" 
            spid="61" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2"     
            lastbatchstarted="2019-01-19T18:12:41.283" 
            lastbatchcompleted="2019-01-19T18:12:41.283" 
            lastattention="2019-01-19T18:12:40.413" clientapp=".Net 
            SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="WIN-****" 
            hostpid="96380" loginname="WIN-JFE5*****" 
            isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="5887012" 
            currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" 
            clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="RemoveSmth" 
                    line="6" stmtstart="188" stmtend="386"     
                    sqlhandle="0x03000600aef2cc644996e400c1a5000001.....">
            DELETE FROM Junction
            WHERE Table1Id=@table1Id AND Table2Id=@table2Id                  
     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf> Proc [Database Id = 6 Object Id = 1691153070]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="19957" dbid="6" subresource="FULL" 
             objectname="Junction" 
             id="lock1af48eb80" mode="X" 
             associatedObjectId="72057594040614912">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process1867be108" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process18679f088" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="19956" dbid="6" subresource="FULL" 
             objectname="Junction" 
             id="lock1af490200" mode="U" 
             associatedObjectId="72057594040614912">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process18679f088" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process1867be108" mode="X" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Do I understand correctly that deadlock occur because of processes different order of page blocking? As I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075885/deadlock-on-a-single-sql-server-table) one possible solution is to add indexes to Junction table FK fields (Is this correct?). Is there another solution for this that I don't know?

Comment: There's loads of online info about deadlocks. It's almost always a good idea to add indexes to FK fields regardless of whether deadlocks occur or not. If you don't have indexes, that is your first task - to analyse workloads and add appropriate indexes. This _usually_ makes read operations faster and therefore reduces the likelihood of deadlocks. Another solution may be to turn on snapshot isolation. Another solution is to look carefully at your code and see if you can do things differently. Both processes in this case are from sqlclient provider so I guess this is from an application?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, they are both threads in c# .net application. If I add an index is there possibility for dedlock to remain (even in theory)?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  I did not expect it when working with a single table. Usually books (online info) says about deadlock when there are several tables and access to them is carried out in a different order.

Comment: "If I add an index is there possibility for dedlock to remain (even in theory)?" Certainly. There's no magic wand for deadlocks. Has a DBA looked at your database or is this a code-first database with no DBA input? Your very first step is to create indexes. How many records are in this junction table and what indexes does it have? The next step is to understand what your application is doing,

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No, this is not code first db. I'm only developer and DBA. There is only index on primary key as I understand. There are near ~34000 records. In that case one process read all order items for customer. Then arter some workload pass it to another process. And finally second process after some other actions can delete some oreder items.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid What conclusion must I made from this situaltion? 1 Add indexes on foreign keys columns. 2. Almost every sql command can cause deadlock. (There's no magic as you said. But is that concludes that I must wrap any sql command code in some kind of retry code that handle deadlock?)

Comment: In the first instance try creating one index in Table1Id,Table2Id although on. 34,000 row table (small) this may not make a difference. Deadlocks are not normal. It’s not normal to have to code retries to allow for them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187105/discussion-between-knightofhell-and-nick-mcdermaid).